# BT Charter fonts with v letter from another font

Tags: fonts, symbols, letters

I'm in the final stages of preparing a manuscript for print with Charter fonts but the italic letter *v* in that font bothers me, because it is too similar to `\nu`.  I would like to use a different font, but **only** for *v, w, y* (and maybe *g*, if avaialable).  I'm looking for advice on:

1. which font would mesh well with Charter and offer better shaped *v, w, y*
2. what sort of incantations I need to add to my preamble to make the switch happen just for these letters

Comment: Do you mean the italic text font or the math font?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: only the math font.  I'm starting to think that maybe I should just use another set of fonts just for math, because I can't find anything that would be close enough in design to Charter to mix with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi use this below coding inbetween `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

You can change any font for specific character, like  v, w, y ...
For changing the font, Now i am using minion font, if you want times font use
`ptm` instead of `pmn`. Like that you can change to any font.

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter

\DeclareSymbolFont{alphabets}{\encodingdefault}{pmn}{m}{it}

\SetSymbolFont{alphabets}{normal}{\encodingdefault}{pmn}{m}{it}

\SetSymbolFont{alphabets}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{pmn}{b}{it}

\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathalpha}{alphabets}{"76}

\DeclareMathSymbol{w}{\mathalpha}{alphabets}{"77}

\DeclareMathSymbol{y}{\mathalpha}{alphabets}{"79}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

Stencils are an effective approach solving the wave equation in
the time domain. Memory bandwidth, not hardware threads, can
easily become the limiting resource if the stencil is parallelized
in the obvious way, because the arithmetic intensity will be low.
Caches ameliorate the problem somewhat, though greater gains can
be obtained by tiling. The problem is a stencil pattern in space
and recurrence pattern in time, so the tiles have a trapezoidal
shape in space--time. The slopes of the sides relate to the
stencil dimensions. Tiling recursively enables a cache-oblivious
algorithm, which optimizes for all possible levels and sizes of
cache while being oblivious to which really exist. Because the
resulting code uses cache more efficiently, it often runs faster,
even when run with a single thread, than the original serial code
runs. $v$ and $w$ and $y$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I accept it.  Is it possible to replace all roman italics in math?  Because, I can't find a good match just for *v* (tried txfonts, bookman, new century schoolbook, utopia), so maybe I should try another font for math italics.